# User edit policy in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, authorization, cakephp-4.x

I have baked policy for users controller. I want to apply policy, so users can edit only their own profiles. But I am struggling with it. I do not know, how to define `$resource`.

If I run code as it was baked, I got *"Policy for NULL has not been defined"*, so looks like `$resource` is not defined.

If have tried to set in controller `$resource = $user->id`, but then I get *"Policy for integer has not been defined"*.

Problem is in `ROOT\vendor\cakephp\authorization\src\Policy\OrmResolver.php`, should I add new resolver?

In `UserPolicy.php`:

```
public function canUpdate(IdentityInterface $user, User $resource)    
    {
        $resource = $user->id;
        return $resource === $user->getIdentifier();
    }
```

In `UsersController.php`:

```
public function edit($id = null)
    {
        ...
        $this->Authorization->authorize($resource, 'update');
        ...
```

I have also tried in `UserPolicy.php` to change: `public function canUpdate(IdentityInterface $user, User $user)`, but then I get fatal error

LessonsPolicy works for me without any problems. `LessonPolicy.php`:

```
public function canUpdate(IdentityInterface $user, Lesson $lesson)
    {
        // logged in users can edit their own lessons.
        return $lesson->user_id === $user->getIdentifier();
    }
```

`LessonsController.php`:

```
public function edit($id = null)
    {
        ...
        //my: apply policy from LessonPolicy.php
        $this->Authorization->authorize($lesson,'update');
        ...
```

Comment: You'll have to be a little more specific here as to what exactly you mean by "_resolving `$resource`_", and what exactly the problem is with the code that you are showing.

Comment: @ndm thank you, I did little update, hope is more clear now

Comment: How exactly are you obtaining the user entity (`$resource`) from the database in your `UsersController::edit()` method? A simple `Table::get()` (which is what bake should generate you) should never give you `null`.

Comment: @ndm, I am lost in this. I have tried to set value for $resource (`$resource = $user->id`). I have never seen such variable in my code before, for the first time when I have baked user policy. In Users table in DB, there is no such value. So I do not know, from where I should get it.

Comment: You have a functioning example right in front of you. Your Lesson edit function reads a lesson entity and passes it to the authorize function. Likewise, your User edit function should read a user entity and pass it to the authorize function.